# So why isn't this actually starting? ServerSocket and Sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to build a web server that I can then pass in get,post, put and delete actions to. Something  basic and simple.

So I decided to write a simple web server that does the following:

```
package aisisplatform.web;

import aisisplatform.web.interfaces.*;
import aisisplatform.web.exceptions.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class WebServer implements WebServerInterface{

    private int bindToPort;
    private Socket socket;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public WebServer(int port){
        bind(port);
    }

    @Override
    public void bind(int port) throws WebServerException {
        if(port == 0 ){
            throw new WebServerException("Cannot bind to port specified");
        }

        bindToPort = port;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws WebServerException {
        try{
           System.out.println("Starting Web Server");
           serverSocket = new ServerSocket(bindToPort);
           socket = serverSocket.accept();
           System.out.println("localhost:" + bindToPort + " is active.");
        }catch(IOException e){
            throw new WebServerException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws WebServerException {
        try{
            System.out.println("Stopping Web Server");
            serverSocket.close();
            socket.close();
            System.out.println("Web Server Stopped");
        }catch(IOException e){
            throw new WebServerException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void restart(){
        System.out.println("Stopping Web Server");
        stop();
        System.out.println("Web Server Stopped");
        System.out.println("Starting Web Server");
        start();
        System.out.println("localhost:" + bindToPort + " is active.");
    }   
}
```

Which is then used in:

```
package aisisplatform;

import aisisplatform.web.*;
import aisisplatform.web.exceptions.*;

public class AisisPlatform {

    private static String[] argumentsArray;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length > 0){
            argumentsArray = args[0].split("=");
            if(argumentsArray[0].equals("--port")){
                WebServer webServer = new WebServer(Integer.parseInt(argumentsArray[1]));
                switch (args[1]) {
                    case "start":
                        webServer.start();
                        break;
                    case "stop":
                        webServer.stop();
                        break;
                    case "restart":
                        webServer.restart();
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new WebServerException("We only allow --port=xxxxx start | stop | restart ");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You then run the app with the parameters of: `--port=xxxxx start | stop | restart` the issue is simple. running the app gets to the line: `System.out.println("Starting Web Server");` and then it just stops.

I have tried debugging it, and playing it through, it sets the port of `47000` but it never finishes starting ... Netbeans is all like "and I set up the server socket and now i am done, allow me to hang here ... " There is no error message thrown nothing.

Comment: Q: Did you try to "connect" to port 47000 from a client?  You can use Windows `telnet localhost 47000` from a command prompt, if you want.

Comment: It *is* starting. It just isn't printing anything until you've accepted a connection, i.e. that message is in the wrong place. What makes you think you can't use zero as a bind port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> running the app gets to the line: System.out.println("Starting Web
>   Server"); and then it just stops.

```
socket = serverSocket.accept();
```

This is a blocking call, and will not return until a client actually connects to your server...

Answer (score 2):

```
 socket = serverSocket.accept();
```

The method blocks until a connection is made. You should use separated thread.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's waiting for the connection needs to be made.

Check the ServerSocket.accept() method comments 

"
Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts 
      it. The method blocks until a connection is made. "

You are starting the ServerSocket(Listener) in the same thread (Main) . So the Main thread will wait until the Connection Made